# LyX export is broken on Mint 16?

Tags: linux-mint, lyx

I've tried LyX Version 2.0.6 from Software Center and 2.0.7 from 3rd party PPA. In both versions, clicking the view button to create a PDF does nothing. There is no error shown, it just has no effect.

**UPDATE**

I can go to document -> settings -> output and choose "DVI" as the format. The button now does *something* but still does not work right.

First it says:

```
No information for converting png format files to eps.
Define a converter in the preferences.
```

Then it says:

```
LaTeX Error: File prettyref.sty not found
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have found this file, which might be `prettyref.sty`:

```
%%
%% This is file `prettyref.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% prettyref.dtx  (with options: `style')
%% 
%% Copyright (c) 1995 Kevin Ruland
%% 
%%
%% prettyref v3.0
%%
%% Copyright 1995,1998.  by Kevin Ruland kevin@rodin.wustl.edu
%%
\ProvidesPackage{prettyref}[1998/07/09 v3.0]
\def\newrefformat#1#2{%
  \@namedef{pr@#1}##1{#2}}
\newrefformat{eq}{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}
\newrefformat{lem}{Lemma \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{thm}{Theorem \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{cha}{Chapter \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{sec}{Section \ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{tab}{Table \ref{#1} on page \pageref{#1}}
\newrefformat{fig}{Figure \ref{#1} on page \pageref{#1}}
\def\prettyref#1{\@prettyref#1:}
\def\@prettyref#1:#2:{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pr@#1\endcsname\relax%
    \PackageWarning{prettyref}{Reference format #1\space undefined}%
    \ref{#1:#2}%
  \else%
    \csname pr@#1\endcsname{#1:#2}%
  \fi%
}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `prettyref.sty'.
```

No idea what to do with it though. `locate *.sty` has tons of paths.

**UPDATE 3**

I have created `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lyx/prettyref.sty` and placed the above contents in it. I then ran `sudo texhash`. Now the error is that it can't find `ulem.sty`! This is going to be miserable, having to track down all these missing files!

Answer (score 1):

For me, installing the packages at the bottom solved is http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu .